# How to insert a 'null' value into a blob field (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i need to insert a "null" value into the blob field of my DB mysql. I have to do it in a servlet.

I tried this way

```
statement.setBlob(1,  null);
```

but i get this error

```
The method setBlob(int, Blob) is ambiguous for the type PreparedStatement
```

I tried even this way

```
statement.setBlob(1,  EMPTY_BLOB());
```

but i get this error

```
The method EMPTY_BLOB() is undefined for the type Name_Of_My_Class
```

Comment: why do you want to insert null.While inserting in insert query you can try following way insert into test(id,name) values(1,'test') and leave the blob field.Null will be inserted automatically http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e11af/1

Comment: Yes i know, but according to the structure of my code, it would be more 'clean' and easier insert a null value, instead of editing my insert string etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
final Blob blob = null;
statement.setBlob(1, blob);
```

or

```
statement.setBlob(1, (Blob) null);
```